# How to play a simple sound clip (like a button click) when a div is clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing an application with the Ionic Framework and searching for a (very) simple way to play a sound every time a div is clicked.  Something similar to this:

```
<div ng-click="sound()"></div>

$scope.sound = function () {
    //sound play once here
}
```

If the solution could be in angularjs that would be great, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$scope.sound=function(){
  var audio = new Audio('audio_file.mp3');
  audio.play();
}
```

Comment: Did you even notice he is talking about an Ionic application?

Comment: Ionic or not. It is still Angular. and its not wrong to use javascript/jquery with it. Angular ships with minimal jquery. He hasn't mentioned in his question that it needs to be ionic framework. He has just tagged it

Comment: if you are developing a hybrid app using cordova, then use this. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media/index.html

Comment: @Ariel, he has just updated his question with those.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why people recommend the vanilla/ng audio methods. This is Ionic Framework, and in order for this to be compatible on all devices (iOS, Android, Windows Phone etc) it's best to stick to Cordova.

Use the [Cordova Media plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/media/) (make sure to have `ngCordova` installed and included in your index.html file, as well as defined as a dependency). Inject `$cordovaMedia` to the controller/service.

In your controller:

```
$scope.myMedia = $cordovaMedia.newMedia('audio/song.mp3'); // Must be relative to index.html to work properly on Android
```

In your view:

```
<button class="button button-positive" ng-click="myMedia.play()">
    Play sound!
</button>

<button class="button button-assertive" ng-click="myMedia.stop()">
    Stop sound!
</button>
```